# Populating user details from the contact list

Tags: ios, uiview, addressbook

I am working on an app and need to make the user enter information like name, phone, address etc. Inside my app is it possible to show the contact list (Address book) and make the user pick the contact he wants to use. I am specifically hoping to find a way that also give me the UI and search functionality within the contacts just like the regular contacts list. So when the user wants to enter the information, I show him the contacts list (with the same UI/functionality or a subset of it) and let him pick the contact. Is there a way to do this in iOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Address book is there. USe that .

This answer can help you.

[Get a list of all contacts on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3747844/get-a-list-of-all-contacts-on-ios)

[Fetch Contacts in iOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19027118/fetch-contacts-in-ios-7)

[How to simply retrieve list of Contacts in iOS7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19655156/how-to-simply-retrieve-list-of-contacts-in-ios7)

If, you want a tutorial, here is the link [Tutorial link](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-import-contact-address-book/)

Comment: Sweet! Thanks! I was pretty sure its there and from what I found I thought the UI part is not there but just a way to get the contact details in code. This is great.